# How to use circledsteps in a caption?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikzlibrary

I am using the [`circledsteps`](https://ctan.org/pkg/circledsteps) package to typeset numbers, as shown in following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\newcommand{\mycircle}{\pgfkeys{/csteps/fill color=yellow}\Circled{123}}
\begin{document}
See Case \mycircle in Figure \ref{myfigure}.
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Case 123}
\label{myfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

However, when substituting the caption for

```
\caption{Case \mycircle}
```

compilation does not finish. What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\pgfkeys` command must be protected when using it in mobile argument; so you should do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\newcommand{\mycircle}{\pgfkeys{/csteps/fill color=yellow}\Circled{123}}
\begin{document}
See Case \mycircle{} in Figure \ref{myfigure}.
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Case \protect\mycircle}
\label{myfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The real problem is that when "moving" the argument to the list for the list of figures, it fails (your version works ok if you do `\caption[case 123]{Case \mycircle}`)

*...But anyway*, the idea is that you set the style once, so what I would do is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\pgfkeys{/csteps/fill color=yellow}
\newcommand{\mycircle}{\Circled{123}}
\begin{document}
See Case \mycircle{} in Figure \ref{myfigure}.
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Case \mycircle}
\label{myfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

or use

```
\newcommand{\mycircle}{\Circled[fill color=green]{123}}
```

for example.

Comment: Is there a difference between using a `circledsteps` command in a `caption` and in a `section`?

Comment: No, they have the same problem --- they are "moving" commands, in the sense that they also save the argument to create a list (of figure, or the table of context). But the `circlesdstep` commands should have no  problem --- the problem was the `\pgfkeys` here, which is "fragile".

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem using `\Circled` in the caption. I also replaced the `center` environment with the `\centering` directive, to remove unwanted vertical spacing.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{circledsteps}
    \newcommand{\mycircle}{\pgfkeys{/csteps/fill color=yellow}\Circled{123}}

    \begin{document}

    See Case \mycircle in Figure \ref{myfigure}.
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Case \Circled{123}}
    \label{myfigure}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]